# Install Webcam driver (Genius facecam 300)

Tags: drivers, webcam

I want to install the genius facecam 300 driver on ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
I saw this website that seems to be useful: http://patchwork.linuxtv.org/patch/11269/; But I do not know how should I use it exactly.

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 093a:2627 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

How can I install that driver?

Comment: did you tried `cheese` to test whether it is working, because in ubuntu generic driver work almost every time. Unlike windows, you don't need to install driver for each component

Comment: @TrailRider: This doesn't look like a duplicate of that question.  The URL in the question is for the `gspca_pac7302` driver, and it looks like the version of that module in 12.04 doesn't yet recognise the questioner's hardware's USB ID.  It isn't simply asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: In fact, It seems that gspca_pac7302 works fine for the 093a:2627;
But I do not know how to make it work!
I did "modeprobe gspca_pac7302" but cheese could not find the webcam yet!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply that patch, you will need to recompile the kernel.  Instructions for doing so can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/

With that in mind, the patch in question appears to be adding an additional USB ID to an existing driver.  It is possible to patch additional IDs into a driver at runtime, so you might be able to get get away without going through a recompile.  You may want to try this even if you plan to recompile the kernel, since it should be enough to verify that the hardware works.

First of all, load the driver in question:

```
sudo modprobe gspca_pac7302
```

Now you need to tell the driver about the new device ID:

```
echo 093a 2627 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/gspca_pac7302/new_id
```

At this point, the driver should bind to the new device.  If it doesn't, try unplugging and replugging it.  You should see a new `/dev/videoN` device file, and maybe some extra log messages in the output of `dmesg` when this happens.

The patch also sets a flag saying that images from this particular device are vertically flipped, so you might notice that in video applications.  I am not sure how you could fix that without the kernel recompile assuming the video application you're using doesn't have some way to correct for this.

Comment: Although I am not at home and have not access to test; Thanks a lot any way Mr. James